# Quick parts document properties from lookup columns?

Tags: list, document, word, quick-parts

I have a list of all of our projects in a site like this: "https://ExampleCompanyName.sharepoint.com/sites/Subsidiary/Lists/Projects/AllItems.aspx"
Here, I have several columns relating to each Project, such as our Project#, our customer's project #, contract#, Project manager, etc. 
In our document library,  "https://ExampleCompanyName.sharepoint.com/sites/Subsidiary/master/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx" this works out well, and we only have to type in our internal Project name and Sharepoint fills out the rest through lookup-columns.

Now, the problem I am having is inserting these lookup columns into Word-files through Quick parts->Document Properties. The only document property I can select is our Project name, the others such as "Project number" is unavailable.

Is there any way of making these document properties available to insert into our Word files? Or do we simply have to insert all the fields manually?