# SP 2013 guidance request: lookup results to be available as document properties

Tags: lookup-column, quick-parts, property

I wish to request some guidance on the best path forward. I have used the Lookup column type for displaying linked information. The 'additional fields' appear as expected. Is there a way to have these 'additional fields' appear as 'site columns' ? I would like use the information contained within the 'additional fields' to be available as 'document properties' so I can dynamically update the working word doc. Sort of a double lookup - user selects cell from list, and based on that selection other 'site columns' get populated.
I see there is another request like this one: [question]: [Quick parts document properties from lookup columns?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/193013/quick-parts-document-properties-from-lookup-columns)

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This proved to be a dead end. Needed to create columns to hold the necessary content. The library where the document is located, needs a workflow to update the columns of interest with the information from the source list.